# What's this container called, which holds vitamin tablets?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Is this a tub, a box, a bottle? Or is there a better word for it?

[image: cylindrical container with screw lid containing 90 chewable Vitamin C tablets]
<sub>(source: [tesco.com](https://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/263/5051622646263/IDShot_225x225.jpg))</sub>

Unfortunately, the [product page](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/263469463) at tesco.com doesn't say what the tablets come in - only that frying information isn't applicable... ;-)

Comment: Chewable pills or powder I guess, you can't chew liquid.

Comment: Perhaps *prescription bottle*

Comment: In the US pills generally come in "bottles". "boxes" are usually made of some kind of paper product (usually cardboard). "tubs" are bathtub shaped containers with a flat top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as it's medicinal in nature, I'd say it was a **bottle**, or more specifically, a **pill bottle**.

If it were a liquid medicine on the other hand, I'd refer to it as a **vial**.

If I were to be more generic, I'd simply refer to it as a **container**.

Edit:
This is a container for another, similar Tesco supplement (in this case it's a multivitamin container)

[image]

The manufacturer refers to the container as a bottle.

Comment: It doesn't look like a vial ))) A vial is typically made of glass and contains liquid.

Comment: I agree. That's why I added the qualifier "if it were a liquid medicine..."

Comment: In Canadian English I would call this a plastic bottle, no matter what was in it.

Comment: It's not a ubiquitous practice to name the container based on its contents. Without a physical referent there may be habitual use, eg calling every medicine container with a lid a "bottle". Recommended action is eliminate this contextual noise about medicine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the rather generic word "container".

This doesn't have the characteristic form of a "bottle" (it has no neck).  "Jar" is associated with an airtight sealed container.  "Pot" suggest ceramics. "Vial" holds liquid. Can or canister suggests an airtight metal container.

So one is forced back a generic term like "container".  I've found [Pharmaceutical Containers](https://www.ampulla.co.uk/product-category/plastic/pharmaceutical-containers/) sold wholesale.

In conversation I'd avoid referring directly to the container:

> Can you get some vitamin pills from the supermarket?

(rather than "a container of vitamin pills)

I'd only use "container" when referring specifically to the packaging.

> The pills come in a plastic container, which is less fragile than glass.

Answer (score 0):

To me (Russian) it's definitely a **'can'**, not a 'bottle' or a 'tub'.

[image: Here's how a can of medicine or pills looks like]

But if we speak about medicine it could really be a ***pill bottle***, ***pharmacy bottle***, or a ***pill container***.

[image: That's what a Pill Bottle, Pharmacy Bottle or a Pill Container looks like]

It could also be a jar, maybe. Plastic jar. I don't agree with *vial*, even a plastic one, since I haven't found any images of a vial looking something similar to the given image.

Comment: As it comes from a UK shop, we definitely wouldn't call it a can, bottle sounds most correct to me. But of course it will differ in other English speaking countries.

Comment: @JamesP I think Russian-English. I've seen many images of cans and canned products to say that this looks exactly like a can. But it's also definitely a pill bottle or a pharmacy bottle or a pill container.

Comment: Maybe a [**can of Pringles**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294441/what-do-you-call-the-pringles-container-that-looks-like-a-bottle) But a can of potato chips (UK *crisps*) is usually lined with that metal looking stuff. [**Canned** sardines](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156158/in-ae-is-tin-used-instead-of-can-to-designate-an-eco-friendly-bpa-free-can/156174#156174), meat, soups etc are metal containers. Plastic is not the same.

Comment: Yes, "can" would be wrong.

Comment: I have never encountered a plastic can.  Cans are always metal.  Even if the can is bottle-shaped, it's called a *bottle shaped can*.  Search it.  Bottles are plastic or glass, never metal (that I can recall).

Answer (score 0):

A technical term for this shape of container is "canister". A Google image search for "canister" produces many images of containers that are approximately the same shape.

[image: TC Max 500 gram Canister]

Identified by vendor as: **TC Max 500 gram Canister**

Answer (score -1):

In a pharmacy this bottle holds medication such as tablets and capsules and they are called amber bottles.

Comment: [Amber refers to the colour](https://www.google.com/search?q=amber+bottles.&sxsrf=ALeKk03_Z68WXtOvhoGl42snfXcSxzCZmg:1593562044646&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=f0OIHbYJI5pjzM%252CdjkYaz1IV1QFTM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kThdpQ3pnmqaPgV9uM-oR9UsTy7vA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV0OSc4arqAhXQ_aQKHY7rAVoQ9QEwAnoECAgQMg&biw=1309&bih=647#imgrc=f0OIHbYJI5pjzM), a dark browny red shade. And this type of bottle is nearly always made of glass, the picture in the question is clearly a different colour bottle made of plastic.